# Modifying R Markdown Flexdashboard to Generate Pages and Tabs for comparisons between pairs of vars using Purrr Loops and HTMLWidgets

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, purrr, flexdashboard

How can I modify my existing R Markdown flexdashboard code to generate a dashboard with pages and tabs corresponding to subgroups and data in a dataframe, using purrr loops and htmlwidgets?

Currently, my code uses purrr loops to create tabs for each subgroup (Species) with a connected flextable and ggplotly plot using crosstalk. However, I want to modify the code so that it generates pages for each Species in the dataset, and within each page, display pairwise comparisons using htmlwidgets.

The current code generates two pages for comparison (not in a loop, hardcoded) and tabs for each species. I would appreciate some guidance on modifying the syntax to generate pages for each Iris Species, and within each page, several tabs that contain an  x y plot each for pairs of dimensions of this species.

I hope the answer may be useful to those analysts, who have no infrastructure to start a shiny server but would like to provide a comprehensive and interactive report, cross-secting groups and subgroups.

Thank you for your help!

````
---
title: "Flexdashboard"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard

---


```{r setup}
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, flexdashboard, crosstalk, plotly, reactable, reactablefmtr, htmltools)


labels <- unique(as.character(iris$Species))

fn_plot <- function(df = iris, x, y, grp ) {
  
  df <- df %>% filter(Species == {{grp}})
  
  df_reactive <- highlight_key(df)  


  pl <-   df_reactive %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = get(x), y =get(y))) +
      geom_point() 
  
  pl <-
    ggplotly(pl)
  
  
  
  t <-     df_reactive %>%  reactable()
      

  output <-
    bscols(widths = c(6, NA),
           div(style = css(width = "100%", height = "100%"),
               list( t)),
           div(style = css(width = "100%", height = "700px"),
               list(pl)))
return(output)

}


hcs <- 
 map(.x = labels, ~ fn_plot(iris, x = "Sepal.Length", y = "Sepal.Width", grp = .x )) %>%
    setNames(labels) 


hcs2 <- 
  map(.x = labels, ~ fn_plot(iris, x = "Petal.Length", y = "Petal.Width", grp = .x )) %>%
    setNames(labels) 

```

Page 1
====================

Column {.tabset .tabset-fade}
-----------------------------



```{r chunkA}

out <- map(seq_along(hcs), function(i) {

  a1 <- knitr::knit_expand(text = sprintf("### %s\n", names(hcs)[i])) 
  a2 <- knitr::knit_expand(text = "\n```{r}")
  a3 <- knitr::knit_expand(text = sprintf("\nhcs[[%d]]", i)) 
  a4 <- knitr::knit_expand(text = "\n```\n")

  paste(a1, a2, a3, a4, collapse = '\n') 

})

```


`r paste(knitr::knit(text = paste(out, collapse = '\n')))`



Page 2
====================

Column {.tabset .tabset-fade}
-----------------------------



```{r chunkB}

out2 <- map(seq_along(hcs2), function(i) {

  a1 <- knitr::knit_expand(text = sprintf("### %s\n", names(hcs2)[i])) 
  a2 <- knitr::knit_expand(text = "\n```{r}") 
  a3 <- knitr::knit_expand(text = sprintf("\nhcs2[[%d]]", i)) 
  a4 <- knitr::knit_expand(text = "\n```\n")

  paste(a1, a2, a3, a4, collapse = '\n') 
})

```

`r paste(knitr::knit(text = paste(out2, collapse = '\n')))`
````

Comment: When you say that you want tabs that contain pairwise comparisons, what exactly are you looking for there?

Comment: I am sorry not to be clear, pairs of x y, dimensions of petals, Sepal.Length, Petal.Length on x y plot. Just an example. cAn be hardcoded or the pairs can be achieved by select (-Species) |> combn(colnames(iris), 2, simplify = TRUE)[,i] 
I corrected my question to explain. It is just to show the mechanism for generating pages AND tabs in flexdashboard in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't played around with flexdashboard, but I've done similar things in R Markdown to generate a flexible number of PowerPoint slides, so here's my attempt.

The general idea is that we use one (& only one) chunk of R code with `results = "asis"` to generate any number of pages, controlled by a function (creatively named `create.page`) that prints out the necessary markdown syntax for each page.

I also made minor changes to the `fn_plot` function, for more intuitive x/y axis labels and kept only relevant columns in each table.

````
---
title: "Flexdashboard"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

```{r setup}
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, flexdashboard, crosstalk, plotly, reactable, reactablefmtr, htmltools)

iris.list <- split(iris, ~Species) %>% lapply(function(d) d %>% select(-Species))

fn_plot <- function(df, x, y) {
  
  df <- df[, c(x, y)] %>% highlight_key() 

  pl <- ggplotly(ggplot(df, aes(x = get(x), y = get(y))) + 
                   geom_point() + 
                   labs(x = x, y = y))
  t <- reactable(df)

  output <-
    bscols(widths = c(6, NA),
           div(style = css(width = "100%", height = "100%"),
               list(t)),
           div(style = css(width = "100%", height = "700px"),
               list(pl)))
  
  return(output)

}

create.page <- function(df.list, i) {

  df.label <- names(df.list)[[i]]
  df <- df.list[[i]]
  df.cols <- colnames(df)

  # define unique pair combinations
  pair.combinations <- expand.grid(seq.int(length(df.cols)), seq.int(length(df.cols))) %>% 
    filter(Var1 < Var2) %>%
    mutate(Var1 = df.cols[Var1], 
           Var2 = df.cols[Var2],
           label = paste(Var1, Var2, sep = " vs. "))

  hcs <- map(.x = seq.int(nrow(pair.combinations)),
             ~ fn_plot(df, 
                       x = pair.combinations$Var1[.x],
                       y = pair.combinations$Var2[.x])) %>%
    setNames(pair.combinations$label)

  out <- map(seq_along(hcs), function(i) {
    a1 <- knitr::knit_expand(text = sprintf("### %s\n", names(hcs)[i])) 
    a2 <- knitr::knit_expand(text = "\n```{r}")
    a3 <- knitr::knit_expand(text = sprintf("\nhcs[[%d]]", i)) 
    a4 <- knitr::knit_expand(text = "\n```\n")
    paste(a1, a2, a3, a4, collapse = '\n') 
    })
  
  cat("Page", i, "-", df.label, "\n")
  cat("====================\n")
  cat("Column {.tabset .tabset-fade}\n")
  cat("-----------------------------\n")

  cat(knitr::knit(text = paste(out, collapse = '\n'),
                  quiet = TRUE))

}

```

```{r iterate, results='asis'}

# wrapping with invisible() to suppress the NULL returns
invisible(lapply(seq_along(iris.list), function(i) create.page(iris.list, i)))

```
````

Thanks for giving me a reason to learn about flexdashboard :)

Comment: I am very grateful for the Idea. Cant’t wait to reach the computer on Monday morning and run it. Have a very good weekend.

Comment: @z-lin Thank you again for the help. I am trying to learn on your code but feel quite bad about  debugging. I am now trying to redo your code so that it accepts group for page, subgroup for tab and x, y per subgroup for a plot. Here is my another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75868173/modifying-r-markdown-flexdashboard-to-generate-pages-and-tabs-for-groups-and-sub I am still fighting but I am too inexperienced yet. I envy your R coding experience.

Comment: No worries & thank you for your kind words. I'll take a look later.